# Element in the union of three disjoint sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Suppose A , B , C are three disjoint sets. $s\in A\cup B \cup C,$. Thereby 's' is in:

- **Exactly one of A,B or C**
- **Exactly one of A,B or C or in all three of them.**

Which one of the above is acceptable?

Comment: What do you think?

Comment: @AsafKaragila  I am pretty confused about this. If the sets consist of discrete elements then statement 1 . Does it make sense?

Comment: What do you mean by "discrete elements"?

Comment: Firstly when there sets are disjoint there cannot be any element which belongs to all three of them at the same time.... Right?? Now I feel really stupid for having asked something like this.
Secondly, although it doesn't matter anymore by discrete I meant unique.

Comment: That was a wonderful way of showing me the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since A , B , C are three disjoint sets, there is no element in intersection of both of them.
Since $s\in A\cup B \cup C,$ $s$ is in (at least) one of them.
Conclusion: *$s$ is in exactly one of A, B , or C*.
Note: If $P$ and $Q$ are two propositions, and $P$ is **True**, then logically, "$P$ or $Q$"  is also **True**. Hence we can also claim that "$s$ *is in Exactly one of A,B or C* **or** *is in all three of them*."